# OData and Entity Framework different Models mapping

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a class used by Entity Framwork, called `EFApplication`.

Following [this link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options#ODataQueryOptions), i want to add `OData` query option to my `Web Api` controller.

However, i don't want to use `EFApplication` class as the query parameters.

I want to use another class used just for the `OData` querying (`ODataApplication`)

Is this possible?

One of the reasons i want to use a different class is because `OData` doesn't support `DateTime` properties, and this means that i need to change it to `DateTimeOffset`, which i cannot do it (without breaking many other things)

```
// class mapped to Entity Frameowrk / Database
public class EFApplication
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}

// class used for OData querying only
public class ODataApplication
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationsController : ApiController
{
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<EFApplication> Get(ODataQueryOptions<ODataApplication> options)
    {
        // how to apply ODataQueryOptions<ODataApplication> query on top of EFApplication

        return result; // IEnumerable<EFApplication>
    }
}
```

Comment: One of possible solutions is to fill EdmModel manually based on EFApplication class but ignore `DateTime` field. Then you should be able to use it OData

Comment: Can you please give me an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this problem with Automapper and its feature Project().To()

```
// ViewModel class mapped to Entity Framework Model class
public sealed class EFApplicationViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

In your Controller for sample:

```
[EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<EFApplication> Get(ODataQueryOptions<ODataApplication> options)
    {
        IQueryable<EFApplication> queryable = EFApplicationRepository.All();
        IQueryable<EFApplicationViewModel> projected = queryable.Project().To<EFApplicationViewModel>();

        return projected;
    }
```

In addition into Automapper you should set a little 'fix' for the DatetimeOffset(again sigh...)

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EFApplication, EFApplicationViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<DateTime, DateTimeOffset>().ProjectUsing(src => src);
Mapper.CreateMap<DateTime, DateTimeOffset>().ConvertUsing(src => DateTime.SpecifyKind(src, DateTimeKind.Utc));
```

Comment: How do i "apply" the options parameter on top of "queryable" items (or on "projected" items)?

Comment: the returned value is filtererd by your OData options without code of your part. The Attribute actives this behaviour. If you want to do something of me complex you can remove the attribute et "apply" your odata parameter with a code like this: </code> options.ApplyTo(projected,{ODataQuerySettings)} <code>

Comment: It doesn't work :( I get this error message: `Cannot apply ODataQueryOptions of 'Api.Web.Api.OData.ODataApplication' to IQueryable of 'Api.Web.Api.Models.EFApplicationViewModel'.
Parameter name: query`

Answer (score 0):

If you block with DateTime, now it's not a problem.

Here's latest release of Web API OData 5.4 RC.

The release note is 
http://odata.github.io/WebApi/5.4-rc/

And here's a basic sample about the [DateTime Support in Web API OData V4](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/datetime-support)